# HTC explorer in boot loop after factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, boot-loop, htc-explorer

I have an htc explorer. It is not rooted. Some time ago I performed a factory reset through settings. But since then, the phone is stuck in a boot loop. I have tried going through recovery mode and performing a factory reset as suggested by most of the pages on the internet but no luck. So can anyone please help? I am damn tensed!

Comment: If a factory-reset doesn't fix it, and also taking out the battery for a minute won't help, you're probably left with a complete fresh install (re-flashing the firmware), or bring it to the service center to check (in case it's a hardware problem).

Comment: @Izzy can you provide me the link to the firmware, all the links in xda were dead.

Comment: No, I can't (as I don't know). But you might wish to take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575).